# Java call to Vector.set() results in 'unchecked' warning

Tags: java, vector, suppress-warnings, defaulttablemodel, unchecked

I am extending `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`, and am adding a method which calls `Vector.set(...)` on a class variable.  It results in an `unchecked` warning, which I want to fix rather than suppress.  Since this isn't extending `Vector`, I can't use `<E>` it seems, and I don't have a way of knowing what type of `Object` will be in the `Vector`.  Suggestions?

Method:

```
/**
 * Replace a row in the dataVector.  Convenience method for 
 * getDataVector().set(index, element)
 * @param rowNum the index of the row to replace
 * @param replaceRow the element to be stored at the specified position
 * @return the element previously at the specified position
 * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
 */
public Vector setRow(int rowNum, Vector replaceRow) {
  return (Vector)dataVector.set(rowNum, replaceRow);
}
```

This results in:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to set(int,E) as a member of the raw type Vector
return (Vector)dataVector.set(rowNum, replaceRow);
                             ^
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class Vector
1 warning
```

Comment: Um, if you had to extend a class to use generics with it, then generics would be more or less useless.

Comment: I am not extending the class to use generics, I'm extending it because I wanted a Table class, and the table is a Vector of Vectors. I think maybe DefaultTableModel is a red herring here.  I'm just creating a method that calls Vector.set() and results in a warning.

Comment: Well then... the unchecked warning tells you that you're using raw types. The only way to fix the warning (suppressing != fixing) is to not use raw types, which means not using DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I did not realize that DefaultTableModel was using an unparameterized, raw type for `dataVector`. I think in this case, all you can really do is slap on a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation for that function (which will make the compiler stop complaining), javadoc it thoroughly, and call it a day:

```java
/* DOCUMENT THIS THOROUGHLY */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Vector setRow(final int rowNum, final Vector replaceRow) {
    return (Vector)dataVector.set(rowNum, replaceRow);
}
```

---

### Old answer:

Based on your code, it looks like what you really want to do is this:

```java
Vector<Vector<Object>> dataVector = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

public Vector<Object> setRow(final int rowNum, final Vector<Object> replaceRow) {
    return dataVector.set(rowNum, replaceRow);
}
```

The way your code is written/designed, it appears that `dataVector` is intended to actually be a "Vector of Vectors", where each element (a Vector) can hold any kind of Object? Using generics this way in your function and `dataVector` will eliminate the unchecked warnings.

If I have misunderstood, please let me know.

Comment: Correct, dataVector is a Vector of Vectors.  This is a class variable of DefaultTableModel.

Comment: See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: If you look at the source code for `DefaultTableModel`, the Vector is not defined as being a `Vector<Object>`, but only a `Vector`.  I tried the code you suggest above and it did not compile (I'm running Java 8).  It results in `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Vector<Object>`

Comment: Yup. Sorry, I did not realize it was using a raw type (have not used swing in a very, very long time).

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think there's another way of handling the compiler warnings in this specific case.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well, but I was just wondering if someone knew something I didn't.  I was surprised to see these `@SuppressWarnings` all over the source code for the Vector class.